# Line graphs with 95% bootstrap confidence interval

Tags: r, ggplot2, boot, linegraph

Hi I matched a sample of individuals from the treatment group and the control group by using the genetic matching approach from the `MatchIt` package. The outcome variables is the average spending of each month. Now I'm trying to generate a line graph to demonstrate patterns of average monthly spending of the treatment and control groups. I would like to add shaded areas to show the bootstrap confidence interval for these lines. The main issue that I encountered include:

**1. Bootstrap in pairs**

Bootstrap resampling for matched sample should be conducted based on each matched pair, not each individual. Thankfully I've got the solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73322360/bootstrap-in-pair-within-a-matched-sample). The code will be provided in the example.

**2. Plotting bootstrap confidence interval**

I'm not sure how I can plot the bootstrap confidence intervals on the graphs.

Here I provide an example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

ID <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L")
Pair <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6)
Treatment <- c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)
Month_1 <- c(300, 150, 450, 100, 200, 300, 400, 600, 650, 150, 200, 400)
Month_2 <- c(400, 600, 650, 150, 200, 400, 500, 250, 700, 200, 300, 500)
Month_3 <- c(500, 250, 700, 200, 300, 500, 500, 250, 700, 200, 300, 500)
Month_4 <- c(600, 700, 650, 250, 500, 550, 600, 700, 650, 250, 500, 550)
Month_5 <- c(700, 200, 800, 300, 900, 800, 600, 700, 650, 250, 500, 550)

    df <- data.frame(ID, Pair, Treatment, Month_1, Month_2, Month_3, Month_4, Month_5)

> df

   ID Pair Treatment Month_1 Month_2 Month_3 Month_4 Month_5
1   A    1         1     300     400     500     600     700
2   B    1         0     150     600     250     700     200
3   C    2         1     450     650     700     650     800
4   D    2         0     100     150     200     250     300
5   E    3         1     200     200     300     500     900
6   F    3         0     300     400     500     550     800
7   G    4         1     400     500     500     600     600
8   H    4         0     600     250     250     700     700
9   I    5         1     650     700     700     650     650
10  J    5         0     150     200     200     250     250
11  K    6         1     200     300     300     500     500
12  L    6         0     400     500     500     550     550
```

In this dataset, "Month_1-5" denote the monthly spending of each individual; "Treatment" denotes if the individual is in the treatment group (coded as 1) or control group (coded as 0); and "Pair" indicates each matched pair. For example, individual A and B is in the sample pair, because they share the same Pair number of "1". Therefore, after bootstrap resampling, if A appears in any sample, B should appear as well.

Here I provide a code to conduct bootstrap resampling and to calculate mean spending for each month across treatment and control groups:

```
### 95% paired bootstrap confidence interval
library(boot)
df <- df %>%
  mutate(Pair = as.factor(Pair))
pair_ids <- levels(df$Pair)

# For mean of Month_1 in control group
est_control <- function(pairs, i) {
  
  # Compute number of times each pair is present
  numreps <- table(pairs[i])
  
  # For each pair p, copy corresponding data indices numreps[p] times
  ids <- unlist(lapply(pair_ids[pair_ids %in% names(numreps)],
                       function(p) rep(which(df$Pair == p),
                                       numreps[p])))

  # Subset df with paired bootstrapped ids
  md_boot <- df[ids,]
                
  # Estimation
  boot_control <- mean(md_boot[md_boot$Treatment == 0, "Month_1"])

  # Return the mean
  return(boot_control)
}
set.seed(1234)
boot_est <- boot(pair_ids, est_fun, R = 10000)
boot.ci(boot.out = boot_est, type = "bca")

# For mean of Month_1 in treatment group
est_treat <- function(pairs, i) {
  
  # Compute number of times each pair is present
  numreps <- table(pairs[i])
  
  # For each pair p, copy corresponding data indices numreps[p] times
  ids <- unlist(lapply(pair_ids[pair_ids %in% names(numreps)],
                       function(p) rep(which(df$Pair == p),
                                       numreps[p])))
  
  # Subset df with paired bootstrapped ids
  md_boot <- df[ids,]
  
  # Estimation
  boot_treat <- mean(md_boot[md_boot$Treatment == 1, "Month_1"])
  
  # Return the mean
  return(boot_treat)
}
set.seed(1234)
boot_est <- boot(pair_ids, est_treat, R = 10000)
boot.ci(boot.out = boot_est, type = "bca")
```

In this case, the bootstrap confidence interval of "Month_1" for control group is [158.3, 441.7], and that for treatment group is [250, 500].

Then I calculate the average monthly spending for the control and treatment groups and then generate the line graph:

```
Monthly_spending <- df %>%
  group_by(Treatment) %>%
  summarise("1" = mean(Month_1, na.rm = T),
            "2" = mean(Month_2, na.rm = T),
            "3" = mean(Month_3, na.rm = T),
            "4" = mean(Month_4, na.rm = T),
            "5" = mean(Month_1, na.rm = T)) %>%
  pivot_longer(c("1":"5"), names_to = "Month", values_to = "Spending")

Monthly_spending %>%
  mutate(Treatment = as.factor(Treatment)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Month, y = Spending, group = Treatment, color = Treatment)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line(aes(group = Treatment)) +
  ggtitle("Monthly Spending") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_colour_discrete("Groups", labels = c("Control", "Treatment")) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

However, I don't know how to add shaded areas around these two lines to indicate the bootstrap confidence intervals from the code that I provided above. Alternatively, I could run the code for each time point again and again, and then document that in the dataset manually to plot the intervals on the graphs. However, I wonder if there's a way to conduct it more efficiently. I would be really grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a very complex way to achieve your end goal. The ggplot2 function `mean-cl_boot` takes an input vector and returns y, ymin and ymax values calculated by a fast bootstrap method. It works directly inside `summarize` too, so we can replace your whole code with:

```r
df %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("Month"), names_to = "Month") %>%
  group_by(Month, Treatment) %>%
  summarize(mean_cl_boot(value)) %>%
  mutate(Month = as.numeric(sub("Month_", "", Month)),
         Treatment = c("Control", "Treatment")[Treatment + 1]) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Month, y, color = Treatment)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(fill = Treatment, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax), 
              alpha = 0.1, color = NA) +
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
  labs(y = "Monthly spending") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know about `mean_cl_boot`. This is very helpful!!